# Reading zlib/gzip compressed data from MS SQL Server using Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm using Python 2.6 to read data from SQL Server. I'm stuck because a column in my DB is varbinary. I'm using pyodbc, and the data type in the Python program is "buffer".

Now, this column in the DB stores gzip compressed text. I'm unable to figure out how to decompress this from Python, given access to the 'buffer' data type.

Any help/pointers please?

This is what I'm doing

```
con = pyodbc.connect(...)
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute('select ...')
row = cursor.fetchone()

if row:
   x = row.varbinary_column_name
   asciistring = zlib.decompress(x) # throws zlib.error: Error -3 while 
                                    # decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `zlib.decompress` work with just zlib format or does it also support gzip transparently? (They are different)

Comment: @pst, I mean just zlib format. Not an actual gzip file or something.

Comment: @Raj No clue then :-) The gzip wrapper/header is just different than the zlib wrapper (both use an identical deflate algorithm though, I believe). Otherwise, verify data in database, then data loaded from DB match expected data. (Just simple md5sum).

Comment: Hmm thanks @pst. I tried to dump to a file `open('file.gz', 'wb').write(x)` - but this doesn't result in a valid gzip file either :-(

Comment: @MattH - the code sample is in the question, and I'm afraid I can't share the data :-(

Comment: @Raj Run some md5sum tests -- see if the data is correct end-to-end (including source) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
print repr(x[:3])
```

A `zlib` stream typically starts with the 3 bytes `x\x9cc`. A `gzip` stream always starts with the 2 bytes `\x1f\x8b`. What do you have?

According to your comment, the resul was `'+J\xcd'`. This doesn't appear to be `zlib` or `gzip`. What documentation do you have? Do you have source code for whatever created that data?

Comment: @Raj: Did this answer help you? If not, why not? If it did, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: John, sorry for the delay. So, I'm doing this:

`print type(x)
 print repr(x[:3])`

The output is:

`<type 'buffer'>`
`'+J\xcd'`